# Launching web-app with database without static ip

Tags: web-development, database-development, mysql

I have created a small web-app and want to deploy it. I have used struts2 and mysql for the database. The problem is that I do not have a static ip to run the app on my machine. Can anyone suggest me hosting services that host java pages and mysql?

Since this is a project I am not doing for money, I would prefer free servers even if they are allowing usage for a short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about takint a [DynDns](http://www.dyndns.com) account?

This is a Dynamic DNS Service which consists of:

- An executable which runs on your PC and sends notifications to DNS Server of your current IP
- The Dynamic Server

You url would consist then of a subdomain of dyndns which ever you choose. Take a look !

Comment: i created an account but have no clue how to proceed.. i am not understanding stuff. please help

Comment: i figured it out. thanx

Comment: take into account however the security concerns !! have at least a good firewall/antivirus solution ;)